# Django + Apache - wsgi trouble

Tags: django, apache, configuration, wsgi

I've been working with Django locally and now I'm trying to push some code to a production Apache environment on an Ubuntu server I have running (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs).

However, I just get a list of files in the directory and nothing else. First of all I ensured that Python was install by running the command Python at the terminal.

I've installed apaache and mod wsgi with the following commands:

sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

And I've tested to see that its enabled.

Here is my wsgi file firstweb.wsgi which is located in root:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/firstweb')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'firstweb.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is my firstweb.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIScriptAlias / /firstweb.wsgi

Alias /static /var/www/firstweb/static 

<Directory /var/www/firstweb/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all 
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and my Django project is located in: /var/www/firstweb/

I honestly can't work out what is wrong here, within the video it is running fine! :(

Edit, here is error log:

```
[Sat Feb 16 16:19:31 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 16:20:46 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 16:20:47 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 16:20:47 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 16:20:47 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:05 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:06 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:06 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:06 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:17 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:20 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:24 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:24 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:24 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:25 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:25 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:37:26 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:38:01 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:39:19 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 16:39:20 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 16:39:20 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 16:39:20 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 16:39:24 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:39:42 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:48:00 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:48:02 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:51 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:52 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:52 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:52 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:55 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:56 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:49:58 2013] [error] [client 131.231.153.48] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 16 16:53:21 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 16:53:22 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 16:53:22 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 16:53:22 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 16:55:34 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 16:55:35 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 16:55:35 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 16:55:35 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 16 17:00:07 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 16 17:00:08 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sat Feb 16 17:00:08 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Feb 16 17:00:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Can you look at your apache logs - should be under /var/logs/httpd or /var/logs/apache

Comment: I've looked at: /var/log/apache2/ and there is three files, I've checked out the error log, I don't see anything obvious besides a python version mismatch:

Comment: show us anyways - also what screen do you get when you test - what does it look like? What's not working about it

Comment: I've added the log, the output should be the Django application, as you can see in the video at 24:02, but it just shows the files in the directory instead, it's as if it is not executing the python

Comment: Where is the `firstweb.conf` file?

Comment: It is inside sites-available within the apache directory (/etc/apache2/sites-available/), I then enable it through a2ensite

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your virtualhost like so:

```
 <Directory /var/www/firstweb/static>
   Order allow,deny
    Option Indexes
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>

   WSGIScriptAlias / /full-system-path-to/firstweb/wsgi.py
```

If that doesn't work - just make a change to the Directory tag and add static to the end like I have above - I think by not adding static, it's displaying the files in the directory

Comment: Nope, this gave me an error about Option Indexes, so I removed it. I also moved my whole project from the web directory to my home directory (/home/ubuntu/firstweb) and I've tried to re-write everything in various ways with no results. I've removed the firstweb directory from the www folder as well. I'm not getting anything from wsgi/apache besides the regular index page.

Answer (score -1):

Configuring your virtualhost like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/production/myApp

<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/production/myApp>
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-path=/var/production/myApp:/var/production/myApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup misite.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/production/myApp/myApp/wsgi.py

Alias /static   /var/production/myApp/static

<Directory /var/production/myApp/static>
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Replaces "/var/production/myApp" to your app path

If you need more help look at this [tutorial](http://www.qlubox.com/blog/?p=17)

Answer (score -1):

Question 1: Did you enable the wsgi mod?

```
sudo a2enmod mod-wsgi
```

Question 2: Where are your AddHandler statements?

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I don't think apache knows how to associate `.wsgi` files to the wsgi application.

Comment: This is where I got my information from, if you want to look at what else they did. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833766